# Needed help to launch SVM classification in eCognition

Tags: remote-sensing, classification, land-classification, ecognition, machine-learning

I would like if somebody help me to launch SVM classification in eCognition.
Have you met any tutorials?
I was searching through ecognition community, but there I find only basic KNN supervised classification tutorial.